# I am executing a Batch Apex class to delete the records from Recycle Bin but the records are not getting delete?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

This is my code:

```
global class EmptyRecycleBin implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    string query ;
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
    List<Account> accns = new List<Account>();
    system.debug('######' + scope);
    delete scope;
     database.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
AsyncApexJob a =
    [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
    TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
    FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =
    :BC.getJobId()];

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setReplyTo('swati.a.agrawal@accenture.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Batch Processing');
    mail.setSubject('Batch Process Completed');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Batch Process has completed');

    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
  }
}
```

This is my Schedualble Class code:

```
global class ScheduleBatchDelete implements Schedulable{

public static String sched = '0 00 12 * * ?';  

global static String scheduleMe() {
    ScheduleBatchDelete SBD = new ScheduleBatchDelete(); 
    return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SBD);
}

public static String CRON_EXP = '0 15 17  * * ? ';

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
            FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :sc.getTriggerId()];
System.debug('#### ' + ct );
    System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
    System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
    System.assertEquals(' 0 15 17 * * ?', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

    EmptyRecycleBin bd = new EmptyRecycleBin ();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(bd,50);             
  }
}
```

when I am checking the status in Scheduled Job, the status is shown as Queued.

Can anyone help me and let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Hi @swati. Welcome to the Salesforce StackExchange. Can you please take some time to edit your question and properly format all of your code? You will not get any answers like this because it is too difficult to read. I suggest checking out the Tour page to see what is possible - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour. Also, here is a link on formatting code in our community - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: We cannot see your `query` - are you using the `ALL ROWS` clause?